# Polymer 2.0, property access

Tags: data-binding, properties, polymer-2.x

I have quite simple component that does a login with username/password. The template has a button which calls the "login()" method. The console shows for username/password both undefined. I tried everything but nothing works. What am I'm doing wrong?

```
<template>
    <style>
        :host {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
    <h2>Hello [[prop1]], authenticated=[[authenticated]]!</h2>
    <div>
        <div><label>Username: </label><input value="{{username::input}}"></input></div>
        <div><label>Password: </label><input type="password" value="{{password::input}}"></input></div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="{{logIn}}" raised>Log in</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Here is the login method:

```
        logIn() {
            console.log("username="+this.username+", password="+this.password);
        }
```

Comment: Try switching ::input with ::change thats what the Documentation is saying https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/data-system scroll down to "Custom change notification events"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe paper-input fixes your Problem

```
<template>
    <style>
        :host {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
    <h2>Hello [[prop1]], authenticated=[[authenticated]]!</h2>
    <div>
        <div><label>Username: </label><paper-input id="usn" value="{{username}}"></input></div>
        <div><label>Password: </label><paper-input id="pwd" type="password" value="{{password}}"></input></div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="[[logIn]]" raised>Log in</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

On the other hand you could try changing you logIn method to this should also work with just an input don´t forget to set an id:

```
logIn() {
        console.log("username="+this.$.usn.value+", password="+this.$.pwd.value);
    }
```